# Number of combinations of distributing $n$ balls of $k$ colors to $m$ bins with minimum capacity $c$

Tags: combinatorics, balls-in-bins

I would like to distribute balls into bins. The balls are indistinguishable in their own color group and the bins are distinguishable and have the same minimum capacity. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scvDJ.png) I read that we can take each color as a separate setup and multiply the number of combinations afterwards (please correct me if I'm wrong).

So we should be left with the problem of distributing $n$ **indistinguishable balls** into $m$ **distinguishable bins** where each bin has the **same minimum capacity** of $c$. Another constraint is that every ball has to be distributed to the bins.

I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213755/how-many-ways-to-place-n-balls-in-k-bins-with-the-minimum-number-of-balls-in) question which should be the exact same problem.
But when I try out the answer on a simple example I don't get the expected result.

[image]

Comment: Please give an example of how the algorithm in the other question gives an unexpected result.

Comment: Let's have 2 bins and 4 balls. Each bin has minimum of 2 balls. So the result should be (4 - 2 * 2 + 2 - 1) choose (2 - 1) which equals to one. I would have anticipated an ordering of the balls such as 1 2 | 3 4; 1 3 | 2 4; 1 4 | 2 3; 2 3 | 1 4; 3 4 | 1 2. I may have missed some, but those are way over 1 possible solution.

Comment: The solution to the referenced question is correct. For 2 bins and 4 balls with a min of 2 balls for each bin, there is obviously only one solution, namely 2 balls in each bin. You have treated the balls as distinguishable. All the solutions in your comment above are the same single solution.

Comment: On a separate point. If you have several colours, you can only treat each colour separately if you have a min for each colour. If you simply require say 2 balls min per bin, irrespective of colour, then you cannot just multiply the answers for the separate colours.

Comment: @almagest Thank you, the balls should be distinguishable. That was the problem. Also, sorry for not clarifying. For each color the minimum capacity is one. So in that case I should be able to separate the colors in distinct problems, right?